# when to reloadData() on UITableView

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, alamofire

**Problem**:  When using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON to populate a `UITableView`, the table view loads but there is a 1 second pause before the data is displayed.  I am not sure where I should be calling `reloadData()` to fix this.

There are various questions about when to call `reloadData()` using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON to populate a `UITableView`, but I have yet to find an answer that solves my problem.

A bit of background:

I am using the Google Places Web API to populate a `UITableView` with Google Place names, addresses and icons.  Originally I was only using SwiftyJSON to accomplish this, but it was taking quite some time for the `UITableView` to load.  Here is some of that code:

`GooglePlacesRequest.swift`:

```
      ...
        var placesNearbyArray: [GooglePlaceNearby]?

        if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: .allZeros, error: nil) {
                let json = JSON(data: data)
                placesNearbyArray = parseNearbyJSON(json)
                completion(placesNearbyArray)
            } else {
                completion(placesNearbyArray)
            }
        } else {
            completion(placesNearbyArray)
        }
    }

    func parseNearbyJSON(json: JSON) -> [GooglePlaceNearby] {

        var placesNearbyArray = [GooglePlaceNearby]()
        for result in json["results"].arrayValue {
            let name = result["name"].stringValue
            let address = result["vicinity"].stringValue

            ...

            placesNearbyArray.append(place)
        }

        return placesNearbyArray
    }
```

And the code from `viewWillAppear` in the `UITableView`:

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        ...

```
    placesRequest.getPlacesNearUserLocation(location, completion: { (googlePlaces) -> Void in
        if let googlePlaces = googlePlaces {
            self.venues = googlePlaces
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    })
}
```

As I said above, this approach was working, but the `UITableView` would often take 3 - 4 seconds to load.  I then decided to use Alamofire along with SwiftyJSON and (posssibly) a cache.

Here are some snippets of the current code:

`GooglePlacesRequest.swift`:

```
    ...

    var placesNearbyArray: [GooglePlaceNearby]?

    request(.GET, urlString).responseSwiftyJSON({ (_, _, json, error) in
        var innerPlacesArray = [GooglePlaceNearby]()
        for result in json["results"].arrayValue {
            let name = result["name"].stringValue
            let address = result["vicinity"].stringValue

            ...

            innerPlacesArray.append(place)
        }
        placesNearbyArray = innerPlacesArray
        completion(placesNearbyArray)
    })
    completion(placesNearbyArray)
}
```

After adding this, I tried to use the same code from `viewWillAppear` in the `UITableView`, but this is what happens:

- The `UITableView` loads much faster
- There is then a 1 second pause before the table view cells are populated.

I have tried to place the new request function in various places in the `UITableView`, such as in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ...

        let placesRequest = PlacesRequest()
        placesRequest.fetchNearbyPlaces(location, completion: { (googlePlaces) -> Void in
            if let googlePlaces = googlePlaces {
                self.venues = googlePlaces
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }

)
```

And I have also tried to call `reloadData()` on the main thread in both `viewWillLoad` and `viewWillAppear`.

The result is always the same...there is a 1 second pause before the `UITableView` loads the data.

Before I even implement my cache, I need to figure out how (and where) to properly make my request.  Can anyone assist me with this?

Comment: Have you tried using time profiler. When lag happens, it can often indicate which function/call is taking too much time. Also, reloadData will always have a delay depending on the complexity of your cell. Each time you call it, it calculates the height of your cells and put the different elements in your cell, make sure you put as much code you can outside of the tableVIew indexPath Cell function. Just to make sure, your problem is about a reloadData that takes too long, correct ?

Comment: Yes that is correct, `reloadData()` does not finish executing until approximately 1 second after the table view loads.  I will try to use a time profiler.

Comment: I would use multiple prinln() with a time (in miliseconds) to check out when is what method called. But the lag could be normal, because 1. it takes time to load your results, 2. it takes time to prepare your cells. Why do not cache your JSON result? And show the user the last cached result? And give him the possibilty to reload the data?

Comment: But in your code you fetch the data from the webservice, and THEN reload (populate) the table. So the 1 second should be normal (to get the data from the webservice)

Comment: Yes, as I stated in my question, the next step I was going to take was to implement a cache.  I was considering using HanekeSwift or just using `NSCache`.

Comment: @derdida I also think it is "normal" behavior, but previously when I was only using SwiftyJSON (not Alamofire + SwiftyJSON) this was not happening (however the table was taking longer to load in general).

Comment: HanekeSwift is fine, you could just save your Request from Alamofire, i think it makes any difference if your using Alamofire and Swift Core to get your data from any webservice (because Alamofire do the same stuff, just more comfortable) - in some if my cases ill just show the user the "last" successful result from my service, so ill just cache the result of the webservice. If there are not too many results, the parsing & creating of your cells should not take too long. I would still show the user a spinner so he knows that any data is still loading (still when it only takes less then 1 sec)

Comment: @derdida Yes, I have a spinner (which I forgot to include in my code) but it is stopping before the data is loaded.  I didn't even think about it, but that is just a matter of stopping it in the right place.  Thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: @derdida would you put the request in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` ?

Comment: Normally it doesnt matter (because you load the results in another thread async from server) - but in general: ViewDidLoad would be (normally) executed 1 time, when the ViewController is initialised, and ViewWillAppear every time when the View becomes visible.

Comment: I ended up using `NSURLCache` and putting the request in `viewWillAppear`.  Would you like to formally answer the question so I can select your answer?